# Use of AutodiscoverURl in exchange apis

Tags: c#

I am using the Exchange apis to access my Email inbox. I am writing the code in C#. I am unable to understand the use of AutodiscoverURL. Every time I Debug it get stuck at "myService.AutodiscoverURL". A blank command prompt opens up after which i am unable to debug. What should i change in the code to debug further? What should i be returning in "RedirectionCallback" ?

```
public class Program
{
    static bool RedirectionCallback(string url)
    {
        return url.ToLower().StartsWith("computername.domain.contoso.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          ExchangeService myService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
          myService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@org.com", "password", "domain");

          myService.AutodiscoverUrl("abc@org.com", RedirectionCallback);
          Console.WriteLine("EWS Endpoint: {0}", myService.Url);
          Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(myService, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
          Console.WriteLine("The folder name is " + inbox.DisplayName.ToString());
          Console.WriteLine("EWS Endpoint: {0}", myService.Url);

          FindItemsResults<Item> findResults =   myService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
          string content = string.Empty;

          foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
          {
              EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(myService, item.Id);
              email.Load();

              content += item.Subject + "\n";
              content += email.From.Address + "\n";
              content += email.Body + "\n\n";

              Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
              Console.WriteLine(email.From.Address);
              Console.WriteLine(email.Body);
        }

        string result = content;
    }
```

}